# Why do the following sql query generate SQL Execution Error

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I have a database generated by Entity Framework 6 code first.

When I run the following query from Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop

```
select * from calibrations
```

Visual Studio changes it into:

```
SELECT        Id, CertificateNumber, Slope, Offset, Correlation, Covariance, Anemometer_Id, ApprovedBy_Id, Batch_Id, CertificateSoftware_Id, CollectionSoftware_Id, 
                     ControlAnemometer_Id, Operator_Id, Type_Id
FROM            Calibrations
```

And it gives the following error:

[image: **strong text**]

If I then remove the Offset column by changing the SQL Query to:

```
SELECT        Id, CertificateNumber, Slope, Correlation, Covariance, Anemometer_Id, ApprovedBy_Id, Batch_Id, CertificateSoftware_Id, CollectionSoftware_Id, 
                     ControlAnemometer_Id, Operator_Id, Type_Id
FROM            Calibrations
```

It completes with no errors.

I am using SQL Server CE. And the Offset columns is part of the table.

I can't find any information about Offset being a keyword or not. But I have tried to put square brackets around Offset like:

```
SELECT        Id, CertificateNumber, Slope, [Offset], Correlation, Covariance, Anemometer_Id, ApprovedBy_Id, Batch_Id, CertificateSoftware_Id, CollectionSoftware_Id, 
                     ControlAnemometer_Id, Operator_Id, Type_Id
FROM            Calibrations
```

This doesn't help.

I have tried to change the name in the POCO:

```
SELECT        Id, CertificateNumber, Slope, IsThisNameTheProblem, Correlation, Covariance, Anemometer_Id, ApprovedBy_Id, Batch_Id, CertificateSoftware_Id, 
                     CollectionSoftware_Id, ControlAnemometer_Id, Operator_Id, Type_Id
FROM            Calibrations
```

This works! Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OFFSET is a reserved word, as documented here (with spelling mistake) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173340.aspx, and enclosing in brackets solves the problem. Not sure why "This does not help" for you, as I cannot repro.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes for some reason it doesn't help to enclose it in square brackets?